# Hardcode email's password to Ubuntu's Mutt

Tags: ubuntu, mutt

How can you hardcode a password to Mutt in Ubuntu?

It should apparently be placed to a .muttrc. 
However, I have not been successful in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this Linux.com article on [Training your Mutt](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/58760) will help.

```
Let's start by looking at a basic POP configuration. 
If you want to retrieve email from a POP server, 
you'll need to set the following in your .muttrc:

set pop_user = "username"
set pop_delete = no
set pop_pass = "password"
set pop_host = "pop.myserver.com"
```

Also look at: [Mutt: how to safely store password?](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/58760)